# Windows Workflow Runtime Concept

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Hello and thanks for reading.

I'm having difficulty understanding the concept of how the runtime is used to execute workflows in the Windows Workflow Foundation.  I would expect a single runtime to be hosted on a machine, and the workflows access this single instance in order to execute themselves.  Does WWF operate in this manner?  Most of the examples I find create a new WorkflowRuntime instance, execute a workflow, and then dispose of the runtime.

How would you use the WWF to operate a single hosted runtime in order to properly manage schedules, in the same manner as an application server?  I feel that I'm misunderstanding the concept of how WWF is "supposed" to be used.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WF4 uses a different workflow runtime for each workflow instance. You new up a WorkflowInvoker or WorkflowApplication for each workflow instance. If you use workflow services you create a single WorkflowServiceHost per workflow type and it manages each instance under the hood but they still have their own runtime components.

BTW WorkflowRuntime is a **WF3** concept not a WF4 one.

Comment: Perfect, that answers my question.  Thanks Maurice!